# Smartface IOS vertical orientation works, horizontal orientation blank

Tags: device, screen-orientation, smartface.io

When the orientation changed for Xcode product of smartface project, black screen appears. For Android horizontal orientation works ok but IOS has problem.
Is there any more setting?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the orientation from Project Details right ?

Can you check the Orientation settings on XCode ?

Maybe  the orientation doesn't send to xCode Project. Is it possible to share orientation settings which you made ?

Comment: Yes I am changing orientation from project details as well as Xcode. Both xcode and smartface orientation clicked four options "Portrait", "Upside Down", "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right"

Comment: Is there any one which work proper orientation in IOS? It seems that it is another bug of smartface after mp3 playing with ios